# How can i edit my config.php file from an html form

Tags: php

I have a configuration.php files where i store values like this 
public $offline = '0';  Lets say i want a button on my page that write the config and change the 0 to 1 so the website goes offline
How can i accomplish this? I play around with php time to time and my knowledge of it is basic. Is this possible some how? I tried fwrite function or something like this but this overwrite the entire file and not a single value.

Comment: Do you have a database for this site? You could select, update a value there. Otherwise you could have a configuration file on your server and write a php script that could interface with that file, but that could open up some security problems if you are not careful.

Comment: Yes, it must be secured, but write a PHP script to read in the entire file, replace the one line, write out the entire file.  You can do it all into memory, or read-write into a temporary file then copy it over the original.  You might want to wait to do this until you are more experienced with PHP.

Comment: Yes i have a database that is easier to do for me, but i wanted to edit the local file, will this cause security flaws even if i just use toggle buttons and dont use any text input?

Comment: Lets say i want to ignore the secure side of it right now for learning purpose, is it possible to show me a code snippet for doing this, documentations are also good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind solved my self using file_put_content writing a simple function